# How to swap first and last letters in each word?

Tags: c#

I have a practice session on C#, and I want to know how can I swap first and last characters in each word of a sentence and lower case them. I have created a string array that represents each word, and in an inner for loop, I am iterating each character in each word. There is my code.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "Hello world";

            string[] words = text.Split(" ");

            string output = "";

            for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < words[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    

                    if (char.IsUpper(words[i][j]))
                    {
                        output += char.ToLower(words[i][j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output += words[i][j];
                    }

                }
                output += " ";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find it easier to use only one loop and convert the word to a char array, swap the start/end and convert it back. `foreach(var word in words)` will enumerate words. `word.ToCharArray()` will give you a character array that you can use a typical "temp char variable" technique to do the swap with, and you can convert the char array back to a string by passing it to the string constructor with `new string(someCharArray)`. You can use the static [Char.ToLower](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.tolower?view=net-5.0) method to change a char to its lower case equivalen

Comment: Also, you can skip the temp variable swap if you like, because the chars you want are available in the `word` string and strings can be indexed like arrays to produce chars. `word[0]` is the first char of the word. In modern c# `word[^1]` is the last char of the word, so you can copy the first/last char of the word into the char array in last/first position respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because It is sunday :-), here is the complete code (my explanations were to difficult):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string output = "ABCD EFGH IJKL";
        string[] outputs = output.Split(' ');

        char[] chars;
        string first,last;
        string flower,llower;
        string result = string.Empty;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < outputs.Length; i++)
        {
            chars = outputs[i].ToCharArray();
            first = new string(chars[0], 1);
            last = new string(chars[chars.Length - 1], 1);
            flower = first.ToLower();
            llower = last.ToLower();

            chars[chars.Length - 1] = flower.ToCharArray()[0];
            chars[0] = llower.ToCharArray()[0];

            result += new string(chars);
            result += " ";
        }
     
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Result: dBCa hFGe lJKi

Comment: The Split() method you use, does not split on characters that normally occur in a text, like comma, period, exclamation mark, question mark, parenthesizes, and the like, and will fail on text that contains these characters. If you do split on multiple characters, you will not be able to recreate the characters between each word with any confidence.

Comment: It looks like you are somewhat focused on optimizing your code for speed, by using a character array, and limiting the amount of time you write to the console.  If that is the case, you should not convert the first and last characters to a string and you should use a StringBuilder or another character array (or similar) to create the result.

Comment: Yes, you are partly right, I'm not focused to optimize the code but I just wanted to give an example on a schoolar question. The code should be adapted, first of all, he has to split the way he wants, I was focused on the swap and an easy way to do it. The split is not part of the answer but I copied the whole code ...

Answer (score 0):

> one idea is to convert each string into an array of chars then, for each array of caracters, get the first and last caracter and convert those caratcter into string  (of one caracter) in order to use the lower function. Then replace the first and last letters with the lower caracters by inverting the 0 index with the last index, in order to swap.

Example for first letter (NO swap just for explaination):

```
string output = "ABCD";
char[] chars = output.ToCharArray();
string firt = new string(chars[0],1);
string lower = firt.ToLower();
string result = output.Replace(chars[0].ToString(), lower.ToString());
```

For the swap of the first letter to the last

Here is a complete code for first letter: result is "BCDa". For the last letter, it is the same idea

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string output = "ABCD";
            char[] chars = output.ToCharArray();

            string firt = new string(chars[0],1);
            string lower = firt.ToLower();
           
            chars[chars.Length-1] = lower.ToCharArray()[0];

            string result = new string(chars);

            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I lowercase and reverse the first and last characters in each word.

#### Solution using a regular expresion

We could use the Split() method of String or Regex, to split on non-word characters, but then we wouldn't be able to output the correct characters between each word, unless we only split on a single character.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CS_Regex {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Match words using a regular experession
            string match_word = @"(\w+)";
            string match_non_word = @"([^\w]*)";
            string pattern = match_non_word + match_word + match_non_word;
            Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
            // Do the match on example data
            string data = "Hello world";
            MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(data);
            // Output the matches
            foreach (Match match in matches) {
                // Get the text before and after the word
                string non_word_before = match.Groups[1].ToString();
                string non_word_after = match.Groups[3].ToString();
                // Get the matched word
                string word = match.Groups[2].ToString();
                // Lower case the first and last characters and swap them
                string firstchar = (word.Length > 0) ? $"{char.ToLower(word[0])}" : "";
                string lastchar = (word.Length > 1) ? $"{char.ToLower(word[word.Length - 1])}" : "";
                string middle = (word.Length > 2) ? word.Substring(1, word.Length - 2) : "";
                string newword = lastchar + middle + firstchar;
                // Output the new word
                Console.Write(non_word_before + newword + non_word_after);
            }
        } // Main
    } // class
} // namespace
```

#### Output from the proposed solution

```
oellh dorlw
```

#### Links

[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)
[Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0)
[Regex.Match Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Seems like homework; maybe clarify if it is and then provide education rather than solution..